# Have US judges ever declared someone not guilty due to determinism?

Tags: united-states, law

I am often confronted with arguments for or against [biological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_determinism) or [social determinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_determinism) versus free will. One of the arguments I hear regularly is that determinism is bad for society because denying the possibility "to have done otherwise" undermines the foundation of our moral system.

As a final point, I heard people name the case of an defendant being exculpated in front of a U.S. court because the judge has been convinced that there is a biological/social determinism that didn't allow the defendant to do otherwise.

While I am not interested in a discussion on the topic of guilt and determinism, I would love to know if such a case has ever taken place. I don't mean cases where clinically verifiable impairment, like alcoholism or a environmentally induced lack of empathy, has been used to *explain* the deed, but a case where the *only* explanation of the act is the argument that a person isn't free to do otherwise as she did *because of determinism* in any way.

Has there ever been a U.S. case where the defendant has been found not guilty, despite committing an otherwise criminal act, because it was argued that it wasn't their fault due to social constructs or biological reasons outside of their control?

Comment: If we are looking at this philosophically, wouldn't any mentally handicapped person on trial satisfy this prerequisite?

Comment: Also, are you restricting the question to trials? Or also allowing examples from appellate review? It would be great to have a notable concrete claim to examine, so that these ambiguities are avoided. Please see our help page on [how to ask](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This question appears to be off topic or at a minimum needs to greatly clarified with regards to exactly what you are trying to get at. Are you referring to, say, a murder trial where the defendant is trying to argue they are not guilty due to determinism or in the much more general sense that is addressed in the [answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/16643/6629) by  @Sancho?

Comment: I have substantially edited the question. However, as @Sancho suggests, it would help to have an example of the claim, so we can be sure we are not tilting at windmills.

Comment: @Oddthinking Must a question always cite a claim, and a notable claim at that, to avoid being closed as off-topic?

Comment: @ChrisW Yes. See [this meta question](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable), which is endorsed by the [help page on asking questions](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It says: "*But if there's any doubt - if one person shows up and disputes the claim (leaves a comment, or flags for moderator attention) - then it's the responsibility of the asker (or your friendly neighborhood editor) to dig up a real, verifiable source*."

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Yes, what I was loking for was an example for a trial with an "unexpected" outcome due to the determination argument. Unfortunately I can't come up with a concrete claim, because this isn't my argument. It sounds something like: "She couldn't have acted differently for this is the person society/her genes/her brain made her be."

Comment: In Canada an interesting case, about sleepwalking, would be [R v Parks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._v._Parks). Though this does not answer the question, being not a US case and more automatism than social determinism, it may prove interesting since it illuminates a judicial standard for *mens rea* vis-à-vis determinism.

Comment: @rob: The first. Although Sanchos answer is interesting, it is too broad to answer my question. Also, please note that **social** determinism isn't the only one I'm asking about, biological determinism of every kind is relevant, too.

Comment: @iphigenie Could you explain how my answer is too broad? Would it have answered your question had I only included one of my examples?

Comment: Also, you say, *Unfortunately I can't come up with a concrete claim, because this isn't my argument.* Please read through our [FAQ on question notability](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable). Even though it's not your claim, we need you to show that somebody has actually made the claim you're challenging.

Comment: @ChrisW: The notable claim rule has several justifications: showing it is worth the effort to research, showing it is not a straw-man, helping us to define terms and ensure the OP isn't misreading it. As far as I am concerned, if it meets those standards even without a link, I won't vote to close. (That's not to say others won't.) Examples: if commenters say 'Yes, my mother used to say that to me too when I was a kid.', I don't think a link is required. If someone feels motivated to write a good answer that sufficiently defines the question, I don't see any point in closing it.

Comment: @Sancho I will try to explain why your answer didn't answer my question: illness, like alcoholism, is a perfectly well accepted *reason* for acting out of norm. We wouldn't charge a mentally challenged person the same way we would a seemingly healthy one. That is not the point I wanted to make. Of course personal features do often play a role during the trial. But saying that a seemingly healthy person couldn't have done otherwise because that is what her brain made her do because of the neuronal connections in that brain, that is something entirely different.

Comment: @iphigenie So you're looking for an example of a court deciding outside of well-accepted reason? I don't think that's what courts do. Regardless, this would be much clearer if you just quoted and linked to the exact claim that you want examined so we can verify or falsify it.

Comment: @Sancho But I am talking about people I know, people from university. I can't link what they said. I see that the site requests sources and notability, I still don't have them. If that's enough to be off-topic, I will certainly delete this question if you ask me to. By the way, yes, I asked for an example that decided "outside of well-accepted reason". That's exactly what I am looking for for my term paper.

Comment: I think the biggest problem is that the way your question is phrased it is just too long and editorializes a bit too much. Maybe try trimming it down to the bare minimum?

Comment: @rob What do you think that minimum would be?

Comment: @iphigenie Honest I think if you trimmed out the middle two paragraphs and added a transition sentence to go from the first to the last you would probably be good. Notability might be an issue but if you can dig up a link to a scholarly argument about determinism and legal systems that should be covered as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Soft determinism and addiction

In my opinion, a case that could be considered an example of this is *Robinson v. California* 370 U.S. 660 (1962). ([The opinion](http://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/370/660/case.html), [Oral argument audio](http://www.oyez.org/cases/1960-1969/1961/1961_554)).

[Oyez.org](http://www.oyez.org/cases/1960-1969/1961/1961_554) summarizes:

> A California statute made it a criminal offense for a person to "be addicted to the use of narcotics." Lawrence Robinson was convicted under the law, which required a sentence of at least ninety days in jail. A state appellate court affirmed Robinson's conviction on appeal.

The Supreme Court overturned the conviction, holding that that law is unconstitutional.

> The Court likened the law to one making it a criminal offense "to be mentally ill, or a leper, or to be afflicted with a venereal disease," and argued that the state could not punish persons merely because of their "status" of addiction.

I cite this as an example because the court held that a law that punishes somebody for something that is beyond their control is "*an infliction of cruel and unusual punishment in violation of the Eighth and Fourteenth Amendments*". (*Robinson v. California*, at 666)

The court says:

> In this Court, counsel for the State recognized that narcotic addiction is an illness. Indeed, it is apparently an illness which may be contracted innocently or involuntarily. (*Ibid.* at 667)
>
> Not only may addiction innocently result from the use of medically prescribed narcotics, but a person may even be a narcotics addict from the moment of his birth. (*Ibid*. at footnote 9)

"[D]ecisions expanding the Robinson rationale to
reach addiction-related acts, such as narcotics possession, extract from the language of Robinson a second holding, that punishment of involuntary acts
caused by defendant's illness, drug addiction, is unconstitutional." ([*Determinism and the Drug Addiction Defence to Criminal Prosecution*](http://www.law.nyu.edu/ecm_dlv2/groups/public/@nyu_law_website__journals__review_of_law_and_social_change/documents/documents/ecm_pro_072689.pdf), at 365)

Section VI of *Determinism and Drug Addiction Defence to Criminal Prosecution* is a review of a line of cases stemming from the *Robinson* decision. (*Ibid*., at 370)

> Close reading of the cases in the Robinson line reveals one or both
> of these theories in every case. Explicitly or implicitly, courts have relied on
> the in-dwelling agent or soft determinist theories or, in the of cases,
> combinations of both. (*Ibid*.)

It goes on to describe *Easter v. District of Columbia* 361 F. 2d 50 (D.C. Cir. 1966):

> because the alcoholic "could not have done otherwise," he failed to meet the soft determinist criterion of moral responsibility. ([*Determinism and the Drug Addiction Defence to Criminal Prosecution*](http://www.law.nyu.edu/ecm_dlv2/groups/public/@nyu_law_website__journals__review_of_law_and_social_change/documents/documents/ecm_pro_072689.pdf), at 371)

Directly quoting *Easter v. District of Columbia* 361 F. 2d 50 (D.C. Cir. 1966):

> **The alcoholic's presence in public is not his act, for he did not will it**. (at para 1)

It also describes, *Driver v. Hinant* 356 F.2d 761 (4th Cir. 1966):

> **Since the disease has driven the will out of the body**, moral responsibility becomes impossible. ([*Determinism and the Drug Addiction Defence to Criminal Prosecution*](http://www.law.nyu.edu/ecm_dlv2/groups/public/@nyu_law_website__journals__review_of_law_and_social_change/documents/documents/ecm_pro_072689.pdf), at 372)

Directly from *Driver v. Hinant* 356 F.2d 761 (4th Cir. 1966), at para 12:

> This addiction-- chronic alcoholism-- is now almost universally accepted medically as a disease. **Obviously, this includes appearances in public, as here, unwilled and ungovernable by the victim**. Although his misdoing objectively comprises the physical elements of a crime, nevertheless no crime has been perpetrated because the conduct was neither actuated by an evil intent nor accompanied with a consciousness of wrongdoing, indispensable ingredients of a crime.

*Determinism and Drug Addiction Defence to Criminal Prosecution* goes on to summarize several other cases with similar reliance on soft determinism.

### Social determinism

Battered woman/person syndrome has been argued as a defense.

In *State v. Kelly* 22 Ill.97 N.J. 178, 478 A.2d 364 (1984), it was held that:

> The testimony of the expert witness would have shown that the Defendant suffered from battered-woman’s syndrome. Evidence of this affliction was relevant to the Defendant’s case insomuch as it arose out of a history of physical abuse from her husband and both explained why she had never left her husband and why her fear that her husband was going to kill her was reasonable for someone in an abusive relationship. (from [casebriefs.com](http://www.casebriefs.com/blog/law/criminal-law/criminal-law-keyed-to-kadish/exculpation/state-v-kelly/2/))

### Harder determinism

If you're looking for examples of harder determinism as defenses, you're not going to find them. The above examples of impaired mental states and related diminished capacity defenses (that I didn't review) are as close as you will get. Even *they* have been reigned in by the courts' desires to refrain from adopting a theory of determinism. (Michele Cotton, *A Foolish Consistency: Keeping Determinism out of the Criminal Law*, 15 B.U. Pub. Int. L.J. 1 (2005-2006))

For example, in *United States v. Brawner* 471 F.2d 969 (1972), while accepting the diminished capacity defense, the court added that it:

> does not permit the receipt of psychiatric testimony based on the conception
> that mental disorder is only a relative concept and that the behavior of every
> individual is dictated by forces—ultimately, his genes and lifelong
> environment—that are unconscious and beyond his control. . . . **[W]e are not
> embarked on enquiry that must yield to tenets of the philosophy of
> determinism. The law accepts free will and blame-worthiness as a general
> premise.**

The U.S. Supreme Court has said:

> It is as universal and persistent in mature systems of law as belief in freedom of the human will and a consequent ability and duty of the normal individual to choose between good and evil. (In *Morissette v. United States.* 342 U.S. 246 (72 S.Ct. 240, 96 L.Ed. 288) (1952))

It also has called a "deterministic view of human conduct" "inconsistent with the underlying precepts of our criminal justice system". (*United States v. Grayson* 438 U.S. 41 (1978))

From *Steward Machine Co. v. Davis*, 301 U.S. 548, 590 (1937) (at 589-590):

> But to hold that motive or temptation is equivalent to coercion is to plunge the law in endless difficulties. The outcome of such a doctrine is the acceptance of a philosophical determinism by which choice becomes impossible. Till now, the law has been guided by a robust common sense which assumes the freedom of the will as a working hypothesis in the solution of its problems.

In my opinion, the strongest rejection of a deterministic theory of law is from *Bethea v. United States*, 365 A.2d 64, 83 n.39 (D.C. 1976):

> Implicit in our treatment of these issues is our recognition that the law rejects the deterministic theory of individual behavior. See United States v. Brawner, supra, at 27, 471 F.2d at 995. While that theory has some adherents, the notion that a person's conduct is a simple function of extrinsic forces and circumstances over which he has no control is an unacceptable contradiction of the concept of free will, which is the *sine qua non* of our criminal justice system. See United States v. Chandler, supra, 393 F.2d at 929. We reaffirm the law's fundamental presumption that regardless of possible environmental misfortune or deprivation, each person is possessed of the capacity to choose his course of conduct. As expressed in United States v. Currens, supra, at 773:
>
> It is only through [the assumption that each individual has the capacity of choice or control over his behavior] that society has found it possible to impose duties and create liabilities designed to safeguard persons and property.

Comment: That edit was VERY helpful, thank you very much for the sources.

Comment: Great answer, saying all the things I thought of but didn't have time to follow up on (and many more that I didn't think of).